# Select rows from a DataFrame by date_range

Tags: python, pandas

i have the following dataframe:

```
       FAK_ART    FAK_DAT  LEIST_DAT      KD_CRM MW_BW       EQ_NR MATERIAL  \
0         ZPAF 2015-05-18 2015-05-31         D     E  100107  S   
1         ZPAF 2015-05-18 2015-05-31         D     B  100107  S   
2         ZPAF 2015-05-18 2015-05-31         D     E  100108  S   
3         ZPAF 2015-05-18 2015-05-31         D     B  100108  S   
4         ZPAF 2015-05-18 2015-05-31         D     E  100109  S   
5         ZPAF 2015-05-18 2015-05-31         D     B  100109  S   
6         ZPAF 2015-05-18 2015-05-31         D     E  100110  S   
7         ZPAF 2015-05-18 2015-05-31         D     B  100110  S   
8         ZPAF 2015-05-18 2015-05-31         D     E  100111  S
```

.
.
.

```
387976    ZPAF 2016-02-12 2016-02-29  CP     B  100686   S   
387977    ZPAF 2016-02-12 2016-02-29  CP     B  100686   S   
387978    ZPAF 2016-02-12 2016-02-29  CP     E  100712   S   
387979    ZPAF 2016-02-12 2016-02-29  CP     B  100712   S   
387980    ZPAF 2016-02-12 2016-02-29  CP     E  100735   S   
387981    ZPAF 2016-02-12 2016-02-29  CP     B  100735   S   
387982    ZPAF 2016-02-12 2016-02-29  CP     B  100735   S   
387983    ZPAF 2016-02-12 2016-02-29  CP     E  100748   S   
387984    ZPAF 2016-02-12 2016-02-29  CP     B  100748   S   
387985    ZPAF 2016-02-12 2016-02-29  CP     E  100760   S
```

now i want to select only the rows with the date 2015-05-31.

i tried little bit around to handle it with date_range but i always get errors:

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

or

> ValueError: Must specify two of start, end, or periods

my idea was that:

```
data_faktura['LEIST_DAT'] = pd.date_range('2016-01-31', '2016-01-31')
```

but then i get an error!

How can i fix or solve that?

Comment: whether the dtype is string or datetime the following should work: `data_fakture[data_faktura['LEIST_DAT'] == '2016-01-31']`

Comment: do i have to assign that on the dataframe again?

Comment: What do you mean assign? Aren't you trying to filter the df?

Comment: yes i meant if i have to do it like that:

data_faktura = data_faktura[data_faktura['LEIST_DAT'] == '2016-01-31']

Comment: yes that should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `LEIST_DAT` and then select by [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
#change 2016-02-29 to your datetime
data_fakture = data_fakture.set_index('LEIST_DAT').ix['2016-02-29']
print (data_fakture)
           FAK_ART     FAK_DAT      KD_CRM MW_BW       EQ_NR MATERIAL
LEIST_DAT                                                            
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100686   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100686   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     E  100712   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100712   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     E  100735   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100735   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100735   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     E  100748   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100748   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     E  100760   S
```

Or [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
data_fakture = data_fakture.set_index('LEIST_DAT').loc['2016-02-29']
print (data_fakture)
           FAK_ART     FAK_DAT      KD_CRM MW_BW       EQ_NR MATERIAL
LEIST_DAT                                                            
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100686   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100686   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     E  100712   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100712   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     E  100735   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100735   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100735   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     E  100748   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100748   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     E  100760   S
```

You can also select by start and end date:

```
data_fakture = data_fakture.set_index('LEIST_DAT').ix['2015-05-31':'2016-02-29']
print (data_fakture)
           FAK_ART     FAK_DAT      KD_CRM MW_BW       EQ_NR MATERIAL
LEIST_DAT                                                            
2015-05-31    ZPAF  2015-05-18         D     E  100107  S
2015-05-31    ZPAF  2015-05-18         D     B  100107  S
2015-05-31    ZPAF  2015-05-18         D     E  100108  S
2015-05-31    ZPAF  2015-05-18         D     B  100108  S
2015-05-31    ZPAF  2015-05-18         D     E  100109  S
2015-05-31    ZPAF  2015-05-18         D     B  100109  S
2015-05-31    ZPAF  2015-05-18         D     E  100110  S
2015-05-31    ZPAF  2015-05-18         D     B  100110  S
2015-05-31    ZPAF  2015-05-18         D     E  100111  S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100686   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100686   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     E  100712   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100212   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     E  100735   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100735   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100735   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     E  100748   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     B  100748   S
2016-02-29    ZPAF  2016-02-12  CP     E  100760   S
```